# How to apply HandlerInterceptor to Spring Boot Actuator endpoints?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm working with **Java 8** and **Spring 1.2.3** to build an application running inside a **Tomcat 7** container.

I do intercept every single call to my web application using a very simple `HandlerInterceptor`, that logs the overall time taken to create a response and the return code for every request.

I activated the actuator endpoints by simply adding the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency, and I add the interceptor by calling

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Application application;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(application.executeTimeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Apparently, all endpoints managed by Spring Boot Actuator (`/info`, `/health` and so forth) do not get intercepted: **how can I make sure the interceptor intercepts all and every call made to my application, including the ones invoking an actuator-provided endpoint?**

Comment: Are you using tomcat or jetty ?

Comment: Tomcat 7 - added to the question too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring Boot 1.x, you can use an `EndpointHandlerMappingCustomizer` to configure the interceptors of the Actuator's endpoints. For example:

```java
@Bean
public EndpointHandlerMappingCustomizer mappingCustomizer() {
    return new EndpointHandlerMappingCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(EndpointHandlerMapping mapping) {
            mapping.setInterceptors(new Object[] { application.executeTimeInterceptor() });
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In tomcat you can also add a valve to intercept calls to the web server. A valve will intercept all enpoints regardless of their interceptor stack.

Here is an example on how to implement a valve in spring boot:

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TomcatConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        final TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        tomcat.addContextValves(new ValveBase() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(final Request request, final Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                getNext().invoke(request, response);
                LOG.debug("Used time to invoke " + request.getRequestURI() + " : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
            }
        });
        return tomcat;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your method and the valve only works within the embeded tomcat. If I generate the .war file and deploy it to a tomcat instance, the valve will not be invoked. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You might have to manually configure it in the context.xml. See the documentation https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html for details.